# Loop function + saving PDF reports

Tags: excel, loops, pdf

I am using the loop function to filter data and to generate a bunch of reports via a drop down menu. I want to save a PDF of each report as as they are created to a specific file location with a specified name.

I have no bugs in the code below - however no PDFs appears in the target file location.

Can someone help identify where I may be going wrong?

Please excuse the code below - my skills are basic at best.

Thanks
HB

```
Sub PC_Report_Summary()

Dim PCreportreq As String
Dim PCfinalrow As Integer
Dim PClastprintrow As Integer
Dim PCclient As String
Dim PCbem As String
Dim PCreportlocation As String
Dim PCreportname As String
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheets("Summary").Range("B13:E1000").ClearContents
Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Range("P10:S1000").ClearContents

Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Select

PCreportreq = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Range("B2").Value
PCfinalrow = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Range("F1000").End(xlUp).Row
PClastprintrow = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Range("P1000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 10 To PCfinalrow
If Cells(i, 6) = PCreportreq Then
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
    Range("P1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial             xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End If
Next i

PClastprintrow = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Range("P1000").End(xlUp).Row
PCclient = Sheets("Summary").Range("C8").Value
PCbem = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Cells(i, 16).Value
PCreportlocation = Sheets("Summary").Range("C9").Value
PCreportname = PCreportlocation & " - " & PCclient & " - " & PCbem & ".pdf"

Sheets("PC Unit Test Report").Activate

For i = 10 To PClastprintrow
Sheets("PC Unit Test Report").Range("D11") = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Cells(i, 16).Value

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    PCreportname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

Next i

Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Range("P10:S1000").Copy
Sheets("Summary").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you manually export your sheet after the code is executed, can you create and open the PDF? And you might check whether C9@Summary has a back slash at the end since your code is not adding that when constructing **PCreportname** variable.

Comment: Hi @hakan, thanks for your quick comment. I can confirm that there is a backslash at the end in C9@Summary. The workbook itself and worksheet with report are able to be saved as a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard to see whether all your folder paths coming from sheet are set up ok but here is an example that works:

```
Sub saveAsPdf()

    Dim dir As String
        dir = "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\"

    Dim sFileName As String
        sFileName = "helloWorld" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "_" & Format(Date, "dd mmm")


    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        dir & sFileName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

I think you are missing the:

```
& Format(Date, "dd mmm")
```

**EDIT:**

Just realized that as you loop for saving new PDFs you are not updating your

```
PClastprintrow = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Range("P1000").End(xlUp).Row
PCclient = Sheets("Summary").Range("C8").Value
PCbem = Sheets("PC Unit 8015").Cells(i, 16).Value
PCreportlocation = Sheets("Summary").Range("C9").Value
PCreportname = PCreportlocation & " - " & PCclient & " - " & PCbem & ".pdf"
```

these should be inside the 2nd loop which saves the pdf, and i assume the path name changes. it is likely saving the same file over itself x10 lol.

Comment: Hi @learnaswego, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately still no luck with following the inclusion of Format(Date, dd mmm") etc....

Comment: can we see the file and dir paths? also my example was a little messed up LOL but is fixed now. maybe you are missing an \ at the end of the dir path? is file name > 255 chars? does place where you are saving have enough space?

Comment: No trouble @learnaswego :) The dir path is C:\Users\R885024\Desktop\Quotes\  and the construct of the file name should be something like "Client_Name-102093895.pdf

Comment: Update - It appears to go through the loop function for each identified report required, however is only saving the final report generated. When saving, the file name it is only picking up the client name (PCclient) and not unique identifier (PCbem in this case). Strange

Comment: Whoops!!!! That fixed it. Thank you very much for your help! Greatly appreciated :D

Comment: glad to be able to help! and remember to select as correct answer :-p